biblatex: change the \finalnamedelim for a single entry
A user has a single bib entry in Greek (all the rest are in English) and wants the finalnamedelim to be "και" instead of "and" for just that entry in the References. Citation is not affected as this is a Reading List, so \nocite{8} is being used.
The suggested questions at
biblatex: Defining finalnamedelim for different parts of a bibliography entry and Multiple \finalnamedelim in biblatex do not address this specific case.
[Edited]
MWE: greek.tex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fontspec,fontsetup}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear,sorting=nty]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{demo.bib}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}

demo.bib
@book{vinogradov2003elements,
  title={Elements of number theory},
  author={Vinogradov, Ivan Matveevich},
  year={2003},
  publisher={Courier Corporation}
}

@book{Νεγρεπόντης1999απειροστικός,
  title={Απειροστικός Λογισμός Ι},
  author={Νεγρεπόντης, Σ. and Σ., Γιωτόπουλος and Γιαννακούλιας, Ε.},
  year={1999},
  publisher={Εκδόσεις Συμμετρία}
}

[end]

What about other words that biblatex could generate for this entry (but may not in this case): "p."/"pp." etc.? Should they be in Greek as well? In that case it would be easiest to go with autolang=other, as package option and langid = {greek}, in the .bib entry. (And you need to load Greek in babel.)

show a small but complete example that can be used for a test.

The user's current use case is just for the "and". Does your suggestion have an equivalent in polyglossia?

MWE added for test.

Using @moewe's suggestions, it comes up with the error "(./greek.bbl)
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape 'LGR/NewCM10-Book.otf(0)/m/it' undefined
(Font)              using 'LGR/NewCM10-Book.otf(0)/m/n' instead on input line 8." (and just the punctuation where the Greek entry should be.

You can use the package option autolang=other, together with an appropriate langid field in the relevant .bib entry to switch the complete language of an entry including strings like "and".
This will only work correctly with a language package.
With babel
\documentclass[greek,english]{book}
\usepackage{fontspec,fontsetup}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear,autolang=other]{biblatex}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{vinogradov2003elements,
  title     = {Elements of number theory},
  author    = {Vinogradov, Ivan Matveevich},
  year      = {2003},
  publisher = {Courier Corporation}
}
@book{Νεγρεπόντης1999απειροστικός,
  title     = {Απειροστικός Λογισμός Ι},
  author    = {Νεγρεπόντης, Σ. and Σ., Γιωτόπουλος and Γιαννακούλιας, Ε.},
  year      = {1999},
  publisher = {Εκδόσεις Συμμετρία},
  langid    = {greek},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}


With polyglossia
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fontspec,fontsetup}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{greek}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear,autolang=langname]{biblatex}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{vinogradov2003elements,
  title     = {Elements of number theory},
  author    = {Vinogradov, Ivan Matveevich},
  year      = {2003},
  publisher = {Courier Corporation}
}
@book{Νεγρεπόντης1999απειροστικός,
  title     = {Απειροστικός Λογισμός Ι},
  author    = {Νεγρεπόντης, Σ. and Σ., Γιωτόπουλος and Γιαννακούλιας, Ε.},
  year      = {1999},
  publisher = {Εκδόσεις Συμμετρία},
  langid    = {greek},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}


Perfect, thank you!
